# How do I use selenium ChromeDriver to scroll the sidebar on Google maps to load more results?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scroll

I’ve run into a problem trying to use Selenium ChromeDriver to scroll down the sidebar of a google maps results page. I am trying to get to the 6th result down but the result does not fully load until you scroll down. Using the `find_element_by_xpath` method, I am successfully able to access results 1-5 and click into them individually, but when trying to use the `actions.move_to_element(link).perform()` method to scroll to the 6th element, it does not work and throws an error message.

The error that I get is:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

However, I know this element exists because when I manually scroll and more results are loaded, the Xpath works correctly. What am I doing wrong? I’ve spent many hours trying to solve this and I haven’t been able to solve with the available content out there. I appreciate any help or insights you can offer, thank you!

````
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.google.com/maps")
time.sleep(7)
page = soup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

#find the searchbar, enter search, and hit return
search = driver.find_element_by_id('searchboxinput')
search.send_keys("dentists in Austin Texas")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
driver.maximize_window() 

time.sleep(7)

#I want to get the 6th result down but it requires a sidebar scroll to load
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='pane']/div/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[13]/div/a")

actions.move_to_element(link).perform()

link.click()

time.sleep(5)

driver.back()```
````

Comment: does using `document.getElementById('id').scrollDown += big_value` work?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I just tried it and it did not work

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that works, it is to target the element in XPATH from the javascript interface of selenium. You must then execute two commands on an instruction (targeting and scroll)

```
driver.executeScript("var el = document.evaluate('/html/body/jsl/div[3]/div[10]/div[8]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div[1]', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue; el.scroll(0, 5000);");
```

this is the only solution that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The search results in the google map are located with `//div[contains(@aria-label,'dentists in Austin Texas')]//div[contains(@jsaction,'mouseover')]` XPath.
So, to select 6-th element there you can do the following

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(@aria-label,"dentists in Austin Texas")]//div[contains(@jsaction,"mouseover")]')

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(results[6]).click(button).perform()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, when using your code I still get and index error code. ```ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(results[6]).click().perform()
IndexError: list index out of range``` This code worked great for the first 4 search results though, but for some reason it is still not scrolling down to load the 6th result. Any other ideas? Or am I not implementing your suggested code correctly?

Comment: You should add some delay / wait / sleep after clicking on the search button before getting the results list.

Comment: If this doesn't help try performing the mouse move without the click, then give a short delay and then click on the element

Comment: Good ideas on both, both of which I have previously tried. So I can hover and make the mouse move over the first five result elements, but as soon as I get to the 6th it says ```IndexError: list index out of range```

Answer (score 0):

I was just implementing scrolling on google map sidebar, it's working on my side. check this code please

```
# selecting scroll body
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div[9]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]').click()


#start scrolling your sidebar
html = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div[9]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]')
html.send_keys(Keys.END)
```

also add the "KEYS" library

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

I hope it would help you.
by the way I have implemented scrapping of google map with its available data and used above code to scroll. check if you have any problem, let me know then

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.google.com/maps/@37.0625,-95.677068,3z')
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID , "searchboxinput"))).send_keys("Bata")
##click search button
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID , "searchbox-searchbutton"))).click()
##clicking firrst result
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH , "//a[@class='hfpxzc']"))).click()

def scrape_result():
    # scroll the page until it ends
    last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
    while True:
        # Scroll to the bottom of page
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, arguments[0]);", last_height)
        # Wait for new videos to show up
        time.sleep(1)
        # Calculate new document height and compare it with last height
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height
    time.sleep(2)
    results = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='Nv2PK tH5CWc THOPZb ']")
    print(f"total videos: {len(results)}")
    links = []
    for res in results:
        print("links >>>>> " , res.text)
        ##link = res.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'div').find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'div').find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a').get_attribute('href')
        link = res.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a').get_attribute('href')
        links.append(link)
    return links

scrape_result()
```